# How does one go about creating patterns in Python or any other programming language?

Tags: python, c++, nested-loops

So I've been trying to figure out the logic behind these fancy patterns that I saw in Python. For example:

```
   #
  # #
 # # #
# # # #
 # # #
  # #
   #
```

I realize that I should use nested loops do achieve this kind of pattern but I don't know how to get around it. I figure that there is a logic to that which can make the creating of any pattern easy based on how many rows I want, for example, let's say U want to increase the above pattern to 11 rows. I should be able give my code the input and it will generate it. So that would be just using a for loop and iterating in the range 11.

However, I'm confused about the nested loops.

Could someone please explain the logic that I need to use to make any form of pattern, of any shape, size or length?

Note: If you use code examples, try to use Python or C++ if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Here is an example of the creation of that kind of pattern in Python 2: http://fullchipdesign.com/pydiamond.htm

Comment: @AlexThornton Thanks, but what I would like to know is if there is a general way of doing any kind of pattern, like is there a method for doing it and be able to just make about any pattern that I want with ease? The nested loops tend to get messy and I would like to know if there is a possibility of some (mathematical) formula which can be used to solve any pattern, making putting it in any language fast and easy?

Comment: Not really, no. I'm not sure what you mean by 'mathematical formula that can be used to solve any pattern, making putting it into a language fast and easy', but there is no simple way to just make any pattern and I don't think there ever will be a way to do what you are suggesting. The methodology varies greatly from pattern to pattern.

Comment: What you're asking isn't possible. The problem starts with how you describe *"any form of pattern, of any shape"*. In what way would you describe the pattern you want to your program? English sentences? Like `create_pattern("house with three windows and a tree next to it")`?

Comment: @LukasGraf I meant patterns like the one in my example but of different shapes (example: triangular shape, square shape), sizes number of rows).

Answer (score 1):

Who doesn't like a little code golf

```
def makeDiamond(i):
    from math import fabs
    for x in range(-i+1,i):
        print "%s%s"%(" "*abs(x), "# "*(i-abs(x)))

       #print " "  abs(x) number of times
       #print "# " i-abs(x) number of times

#Or (which is much harder to read)

def makeDiamond2(i):
    from math import fabs
    "\n".join(["%s%s"%(" "*abs(x),"# "*(i-abs(x))) for x in range(-i+1,i)])

makeDiamond(4)
```

When trying to make shapes write down the numbers you want to see per line and try to find a pattern.
`3,1 |   #`
`2,2 |  # #`
`1,3 | # # #`
`0,4 |# # # #`
`1,3 | # # #`
`2,2 |  # #`
`3,1 |   #`

Which I saw as:
`3,4-3 |   #`
`2,4-2 |  # #`
`1,4-1 | # # #`
`0,4-0 |# # # #`
`1,4-1 | # # #`
`2,4-2 |  # #`
`3,4-3 |   #`

A trick for when you count from i to 0 then back to i is to start negative in your loop and take the absolute value `math.fabs`
`-3,4-3 |   #`
`-2,4-2 |  # #`
`-1,4-1 | # # #`
`+0,4-0 |# # # #`
`+1,4-1 | # # #`
`+2,4-2 |  # #`
`+3,4-3 |   #`

Comment: This is StackOverflow, not codegolf.stackexchange.com. Could you please ungolf and explain your answer, rather than simply posting code the questioner won't understand?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
def isfilled(x,y,n):
  filled="#"
  if (x+y)%2==0:
    filled=" "
  if x+y<n or x-y>n or y-x>n or x+y>3*n:
    filled=" "
  return filled
n=int(raw_input())
for x in range(2*n):
  line=""
  for y in range(2*n):
    line+=isfilled(x,y,n)
  if line.strip()=="":
    continue
  print line.rstrip()
```

Basically you interprete the output as (x,y) coordinates and try to describe the pattern in a mathematical sense, e.g a the black chessboard squares fullfill `x+y mod 2 =0`

The other 4 conditions like `x+y<n` cut away halfplanes from the pattern.

If you got your pattern in vector format, lets say as a svg file, then you could draw arbitrary patters this way in any size

There are libraries which do this kind of ascii-art for (raster)images and even videos:

[libaa](http://aa-project.sourceforge.net/aalib/)
[libcaca](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/libcaca)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my algorithm :

```
def diamond(n):
    l = [' '*(n-i) + ' '.join('#'*i) for i in range(1,n+1)]
    l += reversed(l[:-1])
    return '\n'.join(l)
```

*Description* :

1. `'#'*i` : creates a string with the same pattern repeated `i` times.
2. `' '.join('#'*i)` : adds a space between each `#`. e.g. `i=4` gives `# # # #`. A much easier alternative is `'# '*i` but it gives an extra space at the end.
3. `' '*(n-i)` : adds an offset to the previous string such that the following line will start a column before.
4. Copy the pyramid upside down without the last line (`l[:-1]`). Note that `reversed` can be replaced by `l[-2::-1]`.